# Помогите с решением этой задачи C#

Tags: c#

Пользователь задает массив строк.  Для каждой строки вывести сумму всех чисел, входящих в эту строку.

Comment: Как именно пользователь задает? Через пробел или что? Как именно нужно вернуть результат? Покажите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Задача очень простая, и помощь с ее решением здесь весьма легко получить, нужно лишь должным образом оформить вопрос, только и всего.

Comment: Ну вот, а я только-только написал решение и вопрос закрыли... :)

Answer (score 1):

Сумма чисел строки:

```
int sum(string st){
    int res;
    for(int i = 0; i < st.Lenght; i++){
        res += st[i] - '0';
    }
    return res;
}
```

А если могут быть буквы, то используйте `switch`.

```
switch(st[i]){
    case '1':
        res += 1;
        break;
    case '2':
        res += 2;
        break;
    //так до девяти
    //если ноль или не цифра, то ничего не прибавляется
}
```

Comment: `А если могут быть буквы` с этого места не понял. `if (st[i] => '0' && st[i] <= '9')` - вы это имели в виду?

Comment: @aepot, если буква попадает в switch, то выполняется блок default, если он есть

Comment: А зачем switch да еще и с кучей повторяющегося кода, если с этим справится простой if в одну строчку как я выше показал? Еще у ва  опечатка вот здесь `st.Lenght`, должно быть `st.Length`.

Comment: Кстати этот ответ не решает задачу автора, ему нужна сумма чисел в строке, а не сумма цифр в числе. Я рекомендую его или переписать под условие задачи или удалить.

Answer (score 1):

При условии, что числа целые, а `lines` - входной массив строк:

```
char separator = ' '; // пробел, если разделены пробелом, иначе поменять
for (int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++) {
   var numArr = lines[i].Split(separator); // массив чисел в строке, пока еще в виде строк
   int result = 0;
   for (int j=0; j<numArr.Length; j++) {
      result += int.Parse(numArr[j]);
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Сумма чисел в строке = " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;        

string num1 = "1 2 5 3 4";
string num2 = "5 3 2 1";
string[] array = new string[2] { num1, num2 };

var result = array.Select(x =>
{ 
    return Regex.Matches(x, @"-?\d+").Cast<Match>().Sum(y => int.Parse(y.Value));
});
```

result - IEnumerable, который содержит ответ. Для вывода можешь использовать foreach и Console.WriteLine

Comment: А с числами больше 9?

Comment: @aepot Исправил. Совершенно забыл об этом. Учёл так же отрицательные числа